# Custom background on UITabBarItem not set on second tap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a custom tabbar with custom tabbar items. Everything works as I want it to, besides when a tap has been tapped and is in a selected state, it does not use my custom highlighted background if re-tapped.

So far I set:

```
    UIButton *tap = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [tap setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [tap setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_down"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [tap setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_down"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

I've read that I may need to use the UITabBarDelegate. Any ideas?

Comment: Of which type is your "tap" object?

Comment: Argh, sorry it is a badly written post. It is a UIButton and I delegate the tap to the tabBarController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set:

```
    [tap setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_down"] forState:(UIControlStateHighlighted|UIControlStateSelected)];;
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785008/keeping-a-uibutton-selected-after-a-touch) SO post for details

Answer (score 0):

```
[tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star22.png"]];
```

change two images

Comment: If tabBarItem is of type UITabBarItem, this does not answer my question, which deals with a UIButton. Answer to my own question is above.