# ios horizontal scroll menu - background buttons select

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, uibutton

I try to make an horizontal navigation menu in scrollView. For every items in the menu i had a different image. When i select an item, i would like to change background image of this item, but i don't know why my code doesn't work:

```
for (int i=0; i<12; i++) {
            UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            UIImage *normal=[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1"];
            UIImage *selec=[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon1down"];
            [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(i*larg, 0, 42.0, 43.0)];
            [btn setBackgroundImage:normal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn setBackgroundImage:selec forState:UIControlStateSelected];

            [scrollCat addSubview:btn];
            cx+=42.0;
    }
    [scrollCat setContentSize:CGSizeMake(cx, 43)];
```

Is there a bad thing in this code?

Answer (score 0):

Try `UIControlStateHighlighted` instead of `UIControlStateSelected`.
Highlighted is the state when the user touches your button.
Selected is only used for some controls, like segments ;  a custom button (one that say, stays selected) would/could make use of Selected.

From [the UIControl_Class docs at developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (emphasis mine):

> **UIControlStateHighlighted**
>
> Highlighted state of a control. A control enters this state when a
>   touch enters and exits during tracking and when there is a touch up
>   event. ...
>
> **UIControlStateSelected**
>
> Selected state of a control. *For many controls, this state has no
>   effect on behavior or appearance*. But other subclasses (for example,
>   the UISegmentedControl class) may have different appearance depending
>   on their selected state. ...

Comment: Thanks for your response, it works well but just when i click on an item. what about if i want the button stay with the second background image until i click on another item?

Comment: You can do both selected and highlighted. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785008/keeping-a-uibutton-selected-after-a-touch