# How do I make a button "touch down" if it's a transition between two ViewControllers?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, transition

I know that when I CTRL drag from a button in to the header file I get an option to make it "touch down" instead of "touch up inside" but when I want the button to move between two ViewControllers I cant find any options besides from modal,push etc... Anyone got an idea?[image: Here is a image of the transition]

Comment: Do you mean you want the button to remain selected after it is being pressed? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785008/keeping-a-uibutton-selected-after-a-touch