# iOS UIButton Selected State

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

I want to achieve the following picture's button state. When the "starts.." area is touched, the area is highlighted and a datepicker pops up. My approach is creating a full-width button and place two labels Starts, Today 12:00AM on top of it. When the user touches the button I respond to the action by pulling up a datepicker. Here are my questions.

1. Is this approach conventional?
2. How do I make a button go into a "selected" state? I tried the following to change the background image:

   UIImage *buttonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_carrot.png"]
                               resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 18, 18, 18)];
       UIImage *buttonImageHighlight = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_light_carrot.png"]
                                        resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(18, 18, 18, 18)];
       [self.startDateButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [self.startDateButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageHighlight forState:(UIControlStateHighlighted | UIControlStateSelected)];

However, the button never goes into a selected state. It changes its color briefly.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try setHighlighted after the button triggers:

```
[self.startDateButton setHighlighted:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you Andreas but unfortunately, that doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe you should check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785008/keeping-a-uibutton-selected-after-a-touch

Comment: The button's color is changed while the button is being pressed, but as soon as I put my finger off the button is back to its previous color.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [- tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:) in [UITableViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/) to respond user's touch action, and customize your cell by [- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) in [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/).

Comment: Is it not possible to do it with a UIButton?