# change tint color of button image on different states

Tags: swift, uibutton

Hi I have an issue I can't figure out. I have wrote an extension that helps me colorize transparant PNG's

```
extension UIButton {
    func setImageColorForState(image: UIImage, color: UIColor, forState: UIControlState) {
        let temp = image.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
        setImage(temp, forState: forState)
        tintColor = color
    }
}
```

I use the extension as follows:

```
btn.setImageColorForState(originalImage!, color: UIColor.yellowColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
btn.setImageColorForState(originalImage!, color: UIColor.grayColor(), forState: .Normal)
```

Somehow it only takes the last state only. So in this case the highlight state is ignored. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by subclassing UIButton and overriding the isHighlighted variable, similarly to the accepted answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17602296/4673023).

```
    override open var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            self.tintColor = isHighlighted ? UIColor.red : UIColor.gray
        }
    }
```

or, equivalently:

```
    override open var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            if (isHighlighted) { self.tintColor = UIColor.red }
            else { self.tintColor = UIColor.gray }
        }
```

It's an old question, but I wrote this anyway in case someone incurs in something similar. Tested with Swift 3.2 and 4.0.

---

Although it's currently possible to skip the subclassing part and do the same with a UIButton extension, it shouldn't be done (https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Highlighted will be called just when you press, have you tried with selected state ? Also, you should set selected boolean to true.

Otherwise, it will simply return to normal state and hence, have gray color.

You can refer to this one as well : [Keeping a UIButton selected after a touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785008/keeping-a-uibutton-selected-after-a-touch)

Comment: It doesn't have to stay selected. Just when I press it should change to yellow for a split second to show the user that its been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you a solution for what you are trying to do, but I can tell you whats wrong with your code:

Here you are setting the image for an state:

```
let temp = image.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
setImage(temp, forState: forState)
```

And here you are setting the TintColor. But the TintColor is not related to a specific state. It affects all states of the button.

```
tintColor = color
```

So if your are calling this...

```
btn.setImageColorForState(originalImage!, color: UIColor.yellowColor(), forState: .Highlighted)
btn.setImageColorForState(originalImage!, color: UIColor.grayColor(), forState: .Normal)
```

... you just override the TintColor.

Sry that I have no solution for your problem yet.