# How can I keep a button highlighted in iOS for a certain duration of time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

The button in my iOS app is highlighted programmatically on receiving a certain message. I want to keep the button highlighted only for specified time duration (approximately 5 seconds). Is there a way to do it in Objective-C?

Comment: what exactly you mean by highlight? u change color or you mean default highlight state of uibutton?

Comment: Update your question with relevant code you have so far. Clearly explain what it is you wish to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Their is not direct way to control UIButton highlighted state duration.

Although you can do it very easily.

Just change the `background color` or set `Image` for `UIButton`.

And using this method:

```
  [self performSelector:@selector(removeHighlightedState) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

and in `removeHighlightedState` set you `UIButton` to original state.

For more [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785008/keeping-a-uibutton-selected-after-a-touch)