# How do I make my buttons slightly darker when they are selected, like storyboard buttons?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

For my buttons that I create through the storyboard, when they are clicked they become slightly darker as if there is a shadow on them - the typical behavior when buttons are pressed. However, when I create buttons programmatically, they don't do this - is there a property I can change so that they will darken when selected, like the storyboard buttons do?
PS. I don't mean showsTouchWhenHighlighted — this has another animation, but I am looking for the same animation that storyboard buttons have.

Answer (score 1):

[UIButtons](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton#topics) have a bunch of methods of the form:

```
func setXXX(_ XXX: type, 
          for state: UIControl.State)
```

Where XXX are all the things one might care about affecting button's look (title, titleColor, backgroundImage, etc).

The [control state](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/state) describes all the states the button can be in before, during and after user interaction.  The states you probably care about most are `highlighted` and `selected`.

Interactions of the states can get a little tricky because you need to fully specify the state you're trying to setup the UI for. See a good explanation of that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1785059/294949).

Comment: How would you change the background color? I don't see a function for that, I tried changing it for .touchDown and reverting it for .touchUpInside and .touchUpOutside but then there's a weird glitch where if you scroll it will call the touchdown func but not one of the other two to revert it.

Comment: The proper way is two background images, one each set for the highlighted state.  This also can be done in code.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14525049/294949